# returning a object to the parent function inside an inner function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Im having this problem with javascript functions and returning the right results:

```
function outerFunction(){
    var example =[];
    function innerFunction(){
        example.push("first array item");
        return example;
    }
    innerFunction();
}

alert(outerFunction()); //undefined should be "first array item"
```

I need to return the example array back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with

```
function outerFunction(){
    /// ...
    return innerFunction();
}
```

or if you want to rely on modified `example` variable:

```
function outerFunction(){
    /// ...
    innerFunction();
    return example;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first call innerfunction and then return for that try below code :-

```
 function outerFunction(){
        var example =[];

        function innerFunction(){
            example.push("first array item");
               }                           
        innerFunction();
        return example;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the function `innerFunction`

```
function outerFunction(){
    var example = [];
    function innerFunction(){
        example.push("first array item");
        return example;
    }
    return innerFunction();
}

alert(outerFunction());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8H7B8/